# MFC Win32 | LButtonUp not being received after clicking toolbar button (CMFCToolBarButton::OnClick)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

### What I'm trying to achieve

Well, the title might not have explained the problem very well, so here goes:

I am trying to create a Win32 app using MFC that lets you edit and inspect other windows.
I want the user to be able to select other windows.

I got inspired by the "Find Window Process" tool on the toolbar on sysinternals applications such as ProcessExplorer.

[image]

The way it works is you click, then the window disappears, and then you drag it over the window you want to select. A border pops up around it and when you let go, it selects the window the mouse is over.

### My problem

The problem I was facing is that I don't know how to detect when the user lets go of the mouse on another window.

I detect mouse down using `OnClick` in `CMFCToolBarButton`

I tried using `SetCapture()` but that did nothing.

I tried using `OnNcLButtonUp` and `OnLButtonUp` but neither of them worked. (alongside `SetCapture`)

Here's my code so far (`ChildView.cpp`):

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildView, CWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_TB_LOCATEWINDOW, &CChildView::EnableToolbarButton)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_TOOLS_MESSAGELAUNCHER, &CChildView::EnableToolbarButton)
    ON_WM_XBUTTONUP()
//  ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()
    ON_WM_NCLBUTTONUP()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

....


void CChildView::LocateWindow()
{
    GetParentFrame()->ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE);

    SetCapture();
}


void CChildView::OnNcLButtonUp(UINT nHitTest, CPoint point)
{
    ReleaseCapture();

    GetParentFrame()->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);

    MessageBox(L"Stuff", L"");

    CWnd::OnNcLButtonUp(nHitTest, point);
}
```

I want to mention that the `LocateWindow` function gets called when the toolbar button is clicked (as in mouse down, not mouse down AND up)
It is called from the `OnClick` function.

Here's the code for that:
(I replace the button with `OnToolbarReset`)

```cpp
// CLocateWindowButton.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "WindowHacker.h"

#include "MainFrm.h"
#include "CLocateWindowButton.h"

// CLocateWindowButton

IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(CLocateWindowButton, CMFCToolBarButton, 1)

// CLocateWindowButton member functions

CLocateWindowButton::CLocateWindowButton()
{
}

CLocateWindowButton::CLocateWindowButton(CMainFrame* mainFrame, UINT uiCmdID, LPCTSTR lpszText) : CMFCToolBarButton(uiCmdID, NULL, lpszText)
{
    this->mainFrame = mainFrame;
}


BOOL CLocateWindowButton::OnClick(CWnd* pWnd, BOOL bDelay = TRUE) {
    //(CMainFrame*)m_pWndParent->LocateWindow();
    mainFrame->LocateWindow();

    return FALSE;
}

void CLocateWindowButton::CopyFrom(const CMFCToolBarButton& src)
{
    CMFCToolBarButton::CopyFrom(src);
    mainFrame = ((CLocateWindowButton&)src).mainFrame;
}


//void CLocateWindowButton::AssertValid() const
//{
//  CMFCToolBarButton::AssertValid();
//
//  // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
//}
```

**UPDATE**:

It seems to work when I put it inside an `LButtonDown` event, it just seems to not work when it is being detected from `OnClick` in `CMFCToolBarButton`

Comment: *"I tried using `SetCapture()` but that did nothing."* - It's reasonable to assume that there is a bug in your implementation then. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: You're right, that's my fault.
Fixed it now.
If it is still not enough please tell me

Comment: It seems to work when I call `SetCapture` from `LButtonDown` but not from `OnClick` in `CMFCToolBarButton`

Comment: The base of CChildView is most likely CView, not CWnd - adjust your `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` statement; this probably has nothing to do with your issue, but it could create problems with other message map behavior.

Comment: It surprisingly isn't. (I think this is because I disabled document/view support)

@franji1
In `CChildView.cpp` it extends `CWnd`:
```cpp
class CChildView : public CWnd
...
```

BTW CMainFrame extends CFrameWndEx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in `CMFCToolBar::OnLButtonUp`, after calling `OnClick` in the button, it recaptures the cursor, invalidating our `SetCapture`.

BUT if I return `TRUE` instead of `FALSE` in `OnClick`, the mouse is not recaptured.

So changing this:

```cpp
BOOL CLocateWindowButton::OnClick(CWnd* pWnd, BOOL bDelay = TRUE) {
    //(CMainFrame*)m_pWndParent->LocateWindow();
    mainFrame->LocateWindow();

    //ReleaseCapture();
    this->mainFrame->SetCapture();

    return FALSE;
}
```

To this:

```cpp
BOOL CLocateWindowButton::OnClick(CWnd* pWnd, BOOL bDelay = TRUE) {
    //(CMainFrame*)m_pWndParent->LocateWindow();
    mainFrame->LocateWindow();

    //ReleaseCapture();
    this->mainFrame->SetCapture();

    return TRUE; // The line is changed here
}
```

The message gets sent to `CMainFrame` instead.